# when calling a function including a checkbutton after a tkinter window is created the checkbutton value will always be 0

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox

I'm trying to make a function to create a tkinter window holding a checkbutton. this function is called another Tkinter window is made. whenever i do this, the value of the checkbutton is always 0 even if i select it.

```
from tkinter import *
def go(value):
    print(value)
    value = value.get()
    print("value of checkbox",value)

def test2():
    tk = Tk()


    value = IntVar() 
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(tk, text = "value", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,variable =     value)
    checkbutton.pack()

    button = Button(tk,text = "go", command = lambda:[go(value)])
    button.pack()



window = Tk()

text = Label(window,text = "text")
text.pack()

test2()


window.mainloop()
```

if i do the same thing without the window, the checkbutton works:

```
from tkinter import *
def go(value):
    print(value)
    value = value.get()
    print("value of checkbox",value)

def test2():
    tk = Tk()


    value = IntVar() 
    checkbutton = Checkbutton(tk, text = "value", onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0,variable =         value)
    checkbutton.pack()

    button = Button(tk,text = "go", command = lambda:[go(value)])
    button.pack()



#window = Tk()

#text = Label(window,text = "text")
#text.pack()

test2()


#window.mainloop()
```

maybe the check button in Tkinter is a bit fussy with windows

Comment: Multiple calls to `Tk()` create multiple independent GUI instances, with widgets, vars, etc. that cannot interact with other instances at all.  Use `Toplevel()` instead to create a window that lives in the same GUI instance as your root window.

Comment: Add `master=tk` to your `IntVar()` call

Comment: @jasonharper If we really want to be nit picky, `<tk.Tk>.mainloop()` doesn't stop until all instances of `Tk` and `Toplevel` are closed. Therefore, different instances of `Tk()` can communicate with each other but in very rare circumstances.